# Setting author and co-authors

Tags: author-number, covers

I'm currently translating a paper originally written in PDF to LaTeX and, after hours of painfully inputting formulas, I've come across the problem of not know how to set ~lesser~ participants in the main page. There's the `\author{}` and the multiple author options, but all those would put everyone as equals.

How can I put the author's name as main and have the translators name's still visible but in a "second tier" position on the cover?
This is my document's first page right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Calculation of Factorial N}
\author{Luschny, Peter}
\date{September 2015}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{section}{3}
\newpage{}
```

Which renders a large, centered, Title with the author's name under it and a date. I'd like the translators names to be at one of the bottom corners of that page ideally.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Do you use any packages that provide ways to set up the author block?

Comment: Ops, my bad, first time LaTeX user here. I'm using `\documentclass{article}` and I got a full installation of LiveTeX, so I guess I have a package somewhere that does something like that, just no idea which one.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful if you edited your query to show what you've tried so far and/or indicated what the ideal "look" of solution might be. E.g., should any translator-type contributors be shown in the same font size as the main/ordinary author(s), on the same line as the author(s) or on a separate line, etc?

Comment: @Mico, thanks for the tip! Just did so, see if I managed to make myself more clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two main choices:

- If the translator is an important contributor (in your mind) and therefore warrants being listed close to the main author in the title block, you could try something like this:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \title{Calculation of Factorial N}
  \author{Peter Luschny\\[1ex] 
  \small Peter Pan (Translator)}  % use a smaller font size
  \date{September 2015}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle    
  \end{document}
  ```

---

- If that gives too much prominence to the translator, you could use something like

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \title{Calculation of Factorial N}
  \author{Peter Luschny\thanks{%
      Translator of this article: Peter Pan}}
  \date{September 2015}
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \end{document}
  ```